# Perguntar **apenas** para beneficio próprio?

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica

O mais certo quando alguém faz uma pergunta no PT SO é que o perguntador seja o primeiro a ser beneficiado das respostas que lhe são dadas.

Excepções a esta regra são perguntas sobre assuntos mais genéricos ou que envolvem utilização rotineira por parte de todos os programadores (É mais fácil entender isto quando se vê as perguntas com mais votos).

Com o evoluir do tempo cada vez mais vão aparecendo perguntas mais específicas, ao ponto de ocorrer um de vários cenários:

- O Op responde à sua própria pergunta
- O Op encontra outra abordagem para o seu problema
- Apenas utilizadores que estão bem identificados com o problema de OP conseguem responder à sua pergunta

Em todo o caso o OP fez uma pergunta especifica e em determinadas circunstâncias ele pode pensar que a sua pergunta não terá valor para mais ninguém.

É correcto apagar uma pergunta que foi respondida por mim ou por outra pessoa se eu penso que ela não vai ajudar ninguém? É sequer correcto perguntar se tenho este pensamento? Ou este é um pensamento egocêntrico?

O que devo fazer para evitar este pensamento?

Comment: Dependendo do caso, quando a pergunta é tão específica a ponto de não ajudar ninguém (nem mesmo o AP, que acabou deixando apenas um comentário falando que resolveu), eu marco a pergunta como **Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você tem uma pergunta, sabe a resposta e ela não foi fechada pela comunidade, não faz motivo excluir.

Existem várias perguntas que fiz que pensava que não ajudaria ninguém, mas volta e meia eu vejo que elas tiveram mais visualizações, teve algum voto, etc. Isso mostra que mesmo que você pense que não será de ajuda para ninguém, no futuro ela pode sim ajudar.

> Não se preocupe com a pergunta, se ela realmente não for ajudar mais ninguém, além de você, a comunidade se encarregará de fechar a mesma.

Answer (score 12):

Depende. Algumas perguntas vão ser apenas erros de digitação, ou consequência de alguma circunstância bem especial e é **praticamente impossível** que alguém tenha o mesmo problema, ou que a solução vá se aplicar à outra pessoa. Para casos assim existe a opção de fechar como "Não pode ser reproduzido".

<kbd>[image: Utilize com bastante moderação]

Utilize com bastante moderação</kbd>

Apenas tenha em mente que casos assim não são necessariamente fáceis de encontrar, e nem tem como características as coisas que você apontou:

> - O Op responde à sua própria pergunta
> - O Op encontra outra abordagem para o seu problema
> - Apenas utilizadores que estão bem identificados com o problema de OP conseguem responder à sua pergunta

Responder à própria pergunta pode ser algo [planejado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13347) ou [totalmente acidental](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16246). Nenhum dos dois é errado, ou menos valioso. O mesmo vale para o OP encontrar uma outra abordagem, que não necessariamente *resolve*, mas *evita* ou *[contorna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26189)* o problema inicial. Todos esses são caminhos válidos na tentativa de eliminar um problema.

Compartilhar maneiras de se livrar de um problema que vem te atrapalhando é o objetivo do Stack Overflow. *Quem*, *quando*, *como* ou *por que* são quase irrelevantes, desde que o problema exista e a solução funcione.

Além disso, sempre tenha em mente que as perguntas aqui não tem validade. A resposta pra um problema obscuro pode não ajudar ninguém essa semana, mas um dia vai ser útil a alguém na mesma situação. E se um dia você se deparar com um erro incompreensível desses, encontrar ajuda de alguém que passou pela mesma coisa - mesmo que 2 anos atrás - vai ser de enorme valia.

Comment: Foi o que eu comentei, pensei que essa opção estava lá para isso, hehehe

Comment: +1 pelo círculo a mão livre

Comment: @DH. A arte corre no meu sangue